# Ubuntu 18.04 hard lockup

Tags: 18.04, intel, lockup

I am using Ubuntu (Mate specifically) 18.04 on 7 devices of the same type.  They are all running with a similar configuration and are currently displaying some images and videos on the attached displays.  Occasionally a random device will hard lock with no indication that anything was going wrong.  I have tried to capture logs using netconsole but have not seen anything indicating the cause of the lockup.  The amount of time between lockups is not fixed.

Each device is using an Intel i3 CPU with 8GB of RAM.  The CPU is 80% idle.  After reading through other issues people were having I applied 'intel_idle.max_cstate=1' and that appeared to help at first, but it didn't solve the issue.

The original installation used kernel 5.0.0, but I have updated them to the most recent (via ubuntu updates) to 5.3.0.  I have updated the BIOS on the systems to the most recent version as well.

As a comparison, I installed Windows on a couple just to see if it was hardware-specific, but those kept running without trouble.  I have been looking into this problem for several months and all tests I have performed have not found a root cause.

Is there anything else I might try (kernel command line options, kernel versions, firmware, etc) to see if I can find a way to keep these systems running without hard lockups?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, well prepared. I assume that you need to "hard" reboot after the lock. In that case you might try to read the **previous boot** journal/log data by issuing

```
journalctl -b -1
```

in a terminal. I'm not sure if that helps you, but the lock indicates either a Problem with the CPU or GPU. I guess you are using the intel driver?

Edit.
Not a clean solution ,but you may try to remove the intel microcode - just for a test.

```
sudo apt-get purge intel-microcode
```

Redhat has [written](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2019-microcode-nov) about it and there might be some tweak that renders your GPU useless. 
Since the intel-microcode is a security feature, I'd reinstall it after that test...

Comment: I have used journalctl to check the logs from boots, but nothing out of the ordinary is logged by the system.  I had a system hooked up receiving netconsole data as well, but there were no messages produced when it locked up.
The intel driver is being used on this hardware.

Comment: Since you obviously have no cpu lockup as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1769376) it seems to be a GPU problem. See my edited answer...